# How to mock $el property in JEST vue-test-utils?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

How to mock `$el` property (points to component's HTML element) when testing component? I need to have an access to mocked `$el` in `mounted()` hook. Solution below does not work.

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
     mocks: {
            $el: { 
               //some properties 
            }
     }
})
```

**//Edit**

Ok I found a workaround for this.

If you need access to `this.$parent` or `this.$el` in created/mounted hook, just write a getter method in methods and next, mock it in your wrapper and replace `this.$parent`/`this.$el` by mocked method.

```
const wrapper = mount(Component, 
methods: { 
   getEl: () => {}
}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

It can be also mocked like this:

```
wrapper.vm.$el = {
    offsetWidth: 1200,
    offsetHeight: 1000
};
```

Comment: This won't work in the mounted hook - you don't have access to `wrapper.vm` until after the component is mounted.